# programs hang due to /etc/localtime timeout

Tags: linux

On my server, suddenly most programs stopped working (they just hang). For example midnight commander. When I debug mc with strace, I see it hangs on `stat("/etc/localtime")`

When I try to `cat /etc/localtime` it hangs indefinitely. Can somebody please help ?

Following is the output of `strace cat /etc/localtime`

```
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/etc/localtime"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2530000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd02fe08000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21338, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 21338, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd02fe02000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\357\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1595408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3709016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd02f861000
mprotect(0x7fd02f9e1000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd02fbe1000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x180000) = 0x7fd02fbe1000
mmap(0x7fd02fbe6000, 18520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd02fbe6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd02fe01000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd02fe00000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd02fdff000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd02fe00700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd02fbe1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60b000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fd02fe0a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd02fe02000, 21338)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2530000
brk(0x2551000)                          = 0x2551000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1534672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1534672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd02fc88000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1892, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 32768) = 1892
write(1, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 1892
```

Comment: output of `ls -la /etc/localtime`?

Comment: either that's not a regular file (a FIFO?), or something is severely wrong with physical disk

Answer (score 1):

This looks like memory or disk corruption. Check your system logs (e.g. `/var/log/kern.log`) to see if any disk corruption is mentioned.

Whether you see signs of disk corruption or not, run a memory check. [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is included in many diagnostic suites, or you can download [a bootable image](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso); it's also installed by default on Ubuntu (select it from the boot menu). Let it run for at least one full pass — you can leave it overnight. If it finds an error, replace the bad RAM module immediately.